# How do I set Visual Studio to build a NuGet package?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

How can I get Visual Studio to build a NuGet package for my library component on build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m using a Portable Class Library as the example project.

- Ensure the `NuGet.exe` file in `.nuget` folder is latest.
- Default values come from `AssemblyInfo.cs`, so clean that up.
- Add a NuGet package reference if you do not reference any, preferably something simple like JSON.NET. Often, PCL projects have no external dependencies, in which case no NuGet refs and without any NuGet refs, the required MSBuild config won't get set properly, so we need to add a 'dummy'.
- Enable NuGet Package Restore.
- Edit the NuGet.targets file and ensure `BuildPackage` is `true`.

  ```
  <!-- Property that enables building a package from a project -->
  <BuildPackage Condition=" '$(BuildPackage)' == '' ">true</BuildPackage>
  ```
- Edit your .csproj file and add this to the first, default `PropertyGroup`

  ```
  <BuildPackage>true</BuildPackage>
  ```
- Rebuild your project and then search in the Output for nupkg and confirm creation and location of the package file.
- Remove the dummy NuGet package reference and build again and check the Output.
- To further customize the package creation, you can stick a `MyProjectName.nuspec` file next to your `.csproj` file.

See http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference for more on the NuSpec format. You can also pull one from an existing package (its just a zip file) and have a nose around, see how it was done.

Answer (score 0):

Add a post-build event like this:

```
$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.exe pack "$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" -p Configuration=Release -o "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\Release" -symbols"
```

And download and place `nuget.exe` in the `.nuget` folder alongside your solution file.

You can use `nuget update -self` to keep the .exe fresh.

**Note**

`nuget.exe pack` has a bug currently where it'll see a `packages.config` file and try to look for the packages it mentions in your solution but it fails to find them if the packages folder is in a strange place, e.g. if your solution file isn't a level up from the project.

To workaround this, add another post build event to copy the `packages` folder into the project folder.

The `repositorypath` config setting seems to do nothing for me.

See GitHub reports:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5316

---

So funny. I was having problems with my usual way of auto-building a package on build when I arrived at this new way. So I looked for a suitable SO question to answer with my new post-build method when I came across my own question here!